# Recognize the equation of a surface of revolution

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surfaces

Yesterday, I asked a question about the critic points of the surface

$$z = (x^2 + y^2)e^{-(x^2 + y^2)}$$ and my question was if I had a easier way to classify the critic points of this surfaces without calculating the determinant of the Hessian matrix. Fortunately, I've find out that surface was a revolution surface, which made my job of classifying the points much easier. Unfortunately, I couldn't conclude it by myself, since I do not know (if there is one) the general formula of a rotation surface around the $z$-axis ($y$ or $x$ too).

I couldn't find much about it in the calculus books that I know and searching about it, I didn't make much progress too.

So, is there any general formula for a surface of revolution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can certainly write down the equation of a surface of revolution about an arbitrary axis, but I think you are better off just writing down the Hessian if critical points are all you are trying to find.

Comment: I could find the critical points easily using the first order derivatives, but since $ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 2x exp(-(x^2 + y^2))(1-x^2 -y^2)$ (or something like that), the second order derivatives do not looks like a easy thing to calculate. Having that the surface it the rotation of the curve obtained doing $x=0$, I just need to analize the critial points of a 1 variable function, which is much easier. Clearly $(0,0)$ is minimum, but I dont thinnk that calculating the hessian to classificate the points that satisfies $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is a good idea

Comment: If you multiply the $x$ into $(1-x^2 - y^2)$, it is still just a single application of the product rule, you'll then get $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ for free by symmetry. You could rewrite it in polar form, then it is easy to see that the minimum occurs at 0 and the local maxima occurs at $1/e$, but I don't think the Hessian is that bad in this situation.

Comment: Thanks for your attention :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the surface is given by $z=f(x^2+y^2)$, then it is a surface of revolution around the $z$ axis because its level curves are circles.

However, it may not be as easy to see that $z=f(x^2+y^2)$ as it is in your example. Moreover, the surface may have some other axis of revolution, which will make it even harder to spot.